# Better usage of get_post_meta

Tags: wordpress, optimization

What is the better way to get post meta from a post in a Wordpress website?

Way 1:

```
$meta_1 = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'meta_key_1', true);
$meta_2 = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'meta_key_2', true);
etc...
```

Way 2:

```
function parse_meta($meta, $meta_key){
   $value = $meta[$meta_key][0];
   if(is_serilized($value)){
      $value = unserialize($value);
   }
   return $value;
}

$meta = get_post_meta($post_id);
$meta_1 = parse_meta($meta, 'meta_key_1');
$meta_2 = parse_meta($meta, 'meta_key_2');
etc...
```

Which of these two is better?

Comment: Better for what? For performance or your readability?